# Receive a button, that button will display a list of checkboxes in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm having a problem with my project,
I want to make a button, when I click it, it will show a list of checkboxes, if you find it too confusing, you can see it in the image section, for example, if I click on the "Explore this area" button, a list will appear. The list of checkboxes is as shown in Figure 2, my English is quite poor, hope everyone understands, thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried searching many sources but still not getting the results I want,I need everyone's help

Comment: Hello and welcome. What for do you need help ? Here, on StackOverflow, we're helping on technical issues, debug purposes, etc. We're not helping you with the search part ;)

Comment: hi. use expandable cardview and show or hide sub view